# How would I use date in Next.js api to generate boolean if todo item should be visible?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I might have gotten things all messed up, but I'm trying to build something using only Next.js where if a certain date has passed, my todo items should become visible.

I know I can't simply use new Date() in the client, because that would make it possible for anyone to manipulate the time of the client to render the content visible.

So my question is, it is possible doing something like this with Next.js's built in api?

**/api/todos.js**

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const now = new Date();

  res.status(200).json([
    {
      title: 'Todo 1',
      id: 1,
      isOpened: false,
      canBeOpened: now >= new Date('2021-12-01'),
    },
    {
      title: 'Todo 2',
      id: 1,
      isOpened: false,
      canBeOpened: now >= new Date('2021-12-02'),
    },
  ]);
}
```

I'm planning on hosting this on netlify, but I'm not sure what time they might be using.
Is this approach possible?

Comment: That should be possible. Have you tried it? Is anything not working as expected?

Comment: It is working, but It feels like it's not the correct way to use Date(). I thought Id use an api to get the time. I think I want to do this to be sure I get the correct time. However it seems I cant use the fetch() inside this function to http://worldtimeapi.org/, it says fetch is not defined?